# Processing a JSON string into a Java Array

Tags: java, php, arrays, json

I have this array in json code.

```
$info=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
  array_push($info,$row);
}
$info;
$result_final->lugares_cercanos = $info;
```

Print this:

```
{"logstatus":"1","lugares_cercanos":[{"nombre":"Rio Amazonas","distancia":"5119.000"}{"nombre":"Swissotel Quito","distancia":"5823.000"}{"nombre":"Laguna de Yaguarcocha","distancia":"71797.000"}]}
```

Now, the problem is, How can I put the fields of "lugares_cercanos" into java ArrayList??

I try with this code:

```
{
  JSONArray jdata=post.getserverdata(postparameters2send, URL_connect);
  if (jdata!=null && jdata.length() > 0){
    JSONObject json_data;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> lugares = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    json_data = jdata.getJSONObject(0);
    logstatus=json_data.getInt("logstatus");                        
    lugaresCercanos=json_data.getJSONArray("lugares_cercanos");     

    for (int i = 0; i < lugaresCercanos.length(); ++i) {
      JSONObject rec = lugaresCercanos.getJSONObject(i);
      String name = rec.getString("nombre");
      String dist = rec.getString("distancia");
      lugares.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name,dist));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so what happen after try your code ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
JSONObject j = jdata.getJSONObject("obj");
JSONArray jArray = j.getJSONArray("lugares_cercanos");
int len = jArray .length(); 
for(int i=0; i <len; i++){
  String nombre = jArray .getJSONObject(i).optString("nombre");

  ---------
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The top level structure (i.e. the JSON string you have posted) is not an array but an object.

I don't know what your `post.getserverdata` method does, if there is a version that can return a JSONObject you could use:

```
JSONObject jdata=post.getserverdataobject(postparameters2send, URL_connect);
logstatus=jdata.getInt("logstatus");
lugaresCercanos=jdata.getJSONArray("lugares_cercanos");

...
```

Answer (score 0):

show this error:

Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value {"lugares_cercanos":[{"nombre":"Laguna de Yaguarcocha","distancia":"8686205.000"},{"nombre":"Swissotel Quito","distancia":"8728811.000"},{"nombre":"Rio Amazonas","distancia":"8729333.000"}],"logstatus":"1"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray